# How to convert a vbscript into a one liner?

Tags: windows, vbscript

I got an arbitrary vbscript (.vbs) and one to turn it into a one liner.

I tried to replace the line break (`\n` or `\r\n` depending on your platform) by a collon `:` but this does not work for every sort of line.

An excerpt of the vbscript looks like this:

```vb
Function eQPTbXFQgIHMhx(SCpPBrGbXYL)
    uqOxzKfjGCF = "<B64DECODE xmlns:dt=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" & Chr(34) & " " & _
        "dt:dt=" & Chr(34) & "bin.base64" & Chr(34) & ">" & _
        SCpPBrGbXYL & "</B64DECODE>"
    Set dSlfSWLUy = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")
    dSlfSWLUy.LoadXML(uqOxzKfjGCF)
    eQPTbXFQgIHMhx = dSlfSWLUy.selectsinglenode("B64DECODE").nodeTypedValue
    set dSlfSWLUy = nothing
End Function
```

Comment: If line ends with `_`, remove `_`. Otherwise, add `:`. Also, what the heck are those variable names...

Comment: Yes, this answers the question as well, Thanks for linking

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little python script that converts the vbscript into a one liner and takes care of the string concatenation `& _<new line>`

```py
def convert_to_oneliner(vbscript)
    return (
        open(vbscript, "rt")
        .read()
        .replace("\r", "")
        .replace("\n", ":")
        .replace("\t", " ")
        .replace("& _ :", "& ")
        .replace("& _:", "& ")
    )
```

Notes:

- `\r` is stripped
- `\n` is replaced by colon
- `\t` is replaced by whitespace
- concatenations with newline is replaced by concatenation without new line

Answer (score 0):

First of all "& _" at the end represents a line continuation, replace "_\r\n" with "". Step two, put all lines on a single line with colons separating them.